# Django - models - how to describe a specific bidirectional relation between two models?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have two models: **Person** and **Department**. Each person can work in one department. Department can be run by many people. I'm not sure how to construct this relation in Django models.

Here's one of my unsuccessful tryings [models.py]:

```
class Person(models.Model):
     department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
     firstname = models.TextField(db_column='first_name')
     lastname = models.TextField(db_column='last_name')
     email = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Department(models.Model):
    administration = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
    name = models.TextField()
```

I am aware that the code does not work, because the `Person` class references the `Department` class in its ForeignKey relationship before the Department is defined. Likewise, if I move the Department definition before the Person definition, the `Department` class will reference the `Person` class in its ManyToMany relationships before the Person is defined.

What is the proper way to model this specific relation in Django?
I would appreciate if you could provide the example (I'm a newbie).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the model class name as string, as

```
class Person(models.Model):
     department = models.ForeignKey('Department')
     ....
```

First few lines of django doc on [`foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) relationship explain this.

Comment: I got an error: CommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
temp.Department.administration: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Department.administration' clashes with field name 'Person.department'.
 HINT: Rename field 'Person.department', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Department.administration'.

Comment: @s_sherly, add `related_name` attribute  in the field definition.

Comment: The problem here is that if you create a department and there add a person - and then go to the person, the department is not added. This solution is therefore not truly bidirectional.